# How do I let my friends join my world in MCPE version 0.14.0?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just want my friends to be on my world so we can play, but I don't know if we need to be connected to the same wifi server. I have all my worlds on multiplayer and they are on LAN (whatever that means). Thank you so much whoever replies!! Also I'm not using the multilayer MCPE game. Once again thanks whoever replies and i hope the reply is useful

Comment: Also, my friends are far away from me, hope this info helps

Comment: If your friends are far away, they can't join the server.

Comment: MCPE currently only supports WiFi multiplayer, you need to be like within the same house

Answer (score 0):

In order to let them join, you both need to be on the same Wi-Fi network. Then, for your friends, what appears like a new world but what it says on it is blue will come up and your friends have to tap it so they can join. Also, your worlds can't be on LAN, it's only you that can be on LAN in MCPE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data plan go to settings then personal hotspot, turn it on and let them connect to it. Make a new world or do a previous world and it should show up in their maps, up to 5 people can join the map